# FileZilla shall use SFTP but doesn't

Tags: ubuntu, sftp, filezilla, vsftpd

Setup follows at the end

I have a server running vsftp and I setup user "cu1", so that connection is using a certificate.

I want to setup an SFTP-Server so that I can connect to restricted home folders.

**Current status:**

- Using Putty, I cannot login,as I redirected the shell to /bin/false
- Using FileZilla, I can login. But when stopping vsftpd, I can **ALSO LOG IN**?
- In local mode (so, ftp 127.0.0.1 on the machine), I can login and it seems, that I'm restricted to my home folder as planned.
- If I stop vsftpd, I cannot login using ftp 127.0.0.1 as there's no communication partner.

**Questions**:

- How can I check, if my SFTP is properly running; FileZilla seems to use a different protocol
- Why can FileZilla still access, even if the FTP-Server is not running; does it switch to SCP?

  - And if so: Why is scp possible, when shell is disabled?

**Setup: **

- Ubuntu18.04 Server on AWS with ports 20-24, 990 and 1024-2048 available
- vsftpd on the machine to setup an FTP Server that shall run over SFTP

Users:

- root
- ubuntu (my superuser to connect via SSH)
- ftpsecure to be used by vsftpd
- sftp (as basic user for the sftp; shall access all subuser folders)
- cu1 (a sub user with home folder in /home/sftp/home/cu1)

Thank you for any advice, I'm super confused O_o

Comment: AFAIK `vsftpd` is for FTPS (FTP-on-SSL) and not SFTP (SSH File Transfer Protocol). These two protocols are rather different animals. FTPS is an extension/evolution of FTP,  SFTP is a part of SSH and only requires a SSH daemon on the host.

Comment: D'Oh; they should call it vftpsd then ^^. OK, thank you for the information.

Comment: @Human_BetaRelease The first version of vsftpd was released earlier (Feb 2001) than the very first *draft* of SFTP specification (Jul 2001).